# Are there any stable law distributions where the sum of the random variables is distributed the same as the original?

Tags: probability, statistics

I am currently trying to find a distribution where the sum of iid random variables from the distribution is equivalent to the distribution of each of the random variables itself. More concretely, I am looking for a distribution $F$ where if $X_1, \ldots, X_n \overset{iid}\sim F$, then

$$
\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \sim F
$$

for any $n$.

The closest thing I know of is the Cauchy but the Cauchy works with the average, and the Cauchy does not admit defined moments. I have tried to work with a stable law distribution and play around with terms, but have not been able to find a specification that works. Could someone guide me to a distribution which would work as above? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such distribution except the trivial one where $X_i=0$. If $\phi$ is the characteristic function then we get $\phi^{n}\equiv \phi$ for all $n$. If $|\phi (t)| <1$ this gives (by letting $n \to \infty$) $\phi (t)=0$. But $\phi (0)=1$ and $\phi$ is continuous so we must have $|\phi (t)| =1$ for $|t|$ sufficiently small. It is easy to see from this $X_1=0$ almost surely.

Comment: +1. Perhaps an alternative approach is to say $\phi^2(t)=\phi(t)$ here which implies $\phi(t)=0$ or $1$, and then $\phi (0)=1$ and $\phi$ being continuous in general implies $\phi (t)=1$ for all $t$ here and thus $X_1=0$ almost surely

Comment: @Henry You are right. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks a lot, this is great, a most wonderful argument! On a related side, would you be aware of any distributions where the average or another functional transformation would leave us with marginally identically distributed random variables? I know the Cauchy is one but it has no defined moments. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: @user321627 In the case of Cauchy distribution $\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i$ has  same distribution as $nX_1$. As similar thing happens with any symmetric stable distribution ($nX_1$ gets replaced by $n^{1/\alpha}X_1$ for some $\alpha \in (0,2])$. In the non -symmetric stable case you get $n^{1/\alpha}X_1+c_n$ for some constants $c_n$.

Comment: Thanks for your post, may I ask if you have any resources on how I can derive these constants for the non-symmetric stable case? I have referenced wikipedia but am getting difficulty in obtaining the constants.

Comment: @user321627 You can visit statmathbc.wordpress.com, open the catalog and download my notes on infinitely divisible distributions.

Comment: Thanks for the link! It seems however that it says the "the page could not be found". Would you have an alternative link? I would be really interested to read it. Thank you

Comment: @user321627 Sorry about that. A few of the links are not working but there is a search feature. Please search for 'infinitely divisible.